# Resizing SVG rounded rectangle and preserving aspect ratio

Tags: svg, jointjs

I am trying to define an SVG rounded rectangle that I need later resize using *jointjs* resize function which uses standard SVG *transform="scale()"*. In this case scale function changes everything.

Is there a way to resize rounded rectangle shape without touching rx and ry attributes?
Code bellow shows what I would like to achieve by using some scaling functions (Desired).

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
  <!-- Original -->
  <rect x="10" y="0" rx="10" ry="10" height="50" width="50"/> 
  <!-- Scaled -->
  <rect x="10" y="50" rx="10" ry="10" height="50" width="50" transform="scale(2)"/> 
  <!-- Desired -->
  <rect x="10" y="250" rx="10" ry="10" height="100" width="100" /> 
</svg>
```

Comment: No, there isn't

Answer (score 1):

Don't scale it, resize it. It's pretty easy with jointjs:

```
var rounded = joint.dia.Element.define('basic.Rounded',
    {
        attrs: {
            rect: {
                fill: 'black',
                rx: 10,
                ry: 10,
                // bind the width and height of the DOM element to the shape size
                refWidth: '100%',
                refHeight: '100%'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        markup: '<g class="rotatable"><rect/></g>',
    });


// create instance variations
// I.
new rounded().size(100, 100).position(20, 20).addTo(graph);

// II.
new joint.shapes.basic.Rounded().size(200, 200).position(150, 150).addTo(graph)
```

Result:

[image]

it uses 'special attributes':
https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/joint.html#dia.attributes.refWidth

Answer (score 0):

If you have the shape as a [Vectorizer object](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/vectorizer.html#constructor) (where the SVG DOM element is accessible through the `node` property), e.g.:

```
var vel = V('<svg><rect x="10" y="0" rx="10" ry="10" height="50" width="50"/></svg>');
console.log(vel.node);
// <svg id="v-NUM"><rect x="10" y="0" rx="10" ry="10" height="50" width="50"/></svg>
```

You can then also access the rectangle as a Vectorizer object and change its properties this way:

```
var velRect = V(vel.node.childNodes[0]);
velRect.scale(1).attr('y', 250);
console.log(vel.node);
// <svg id="v-NUM">
//   <rect x="10" y="250" rx="10" ry="10" height="50" width="50" transform="scale(1,1)"/>
// </svg>
```

[`vel.scale`](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/vectorizer.html#prototype.scale) and [`vel.attr`](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/vectorizer.html#prototype.attr) are functions from the [Vectorizer API](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/vectorizer.html).